# MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, node.js

I can't make a simple connection to the server for some reason. I install the newest MySQL Community 8.0 database along with Node.JS with default settings.

**This is my node.js code**

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "password",
      insecureAuth : true
    });
    
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
    });
```

**Below is the error found in Command Prompt:**

```
C:\Users\mysql-test>node app.js
    C:\Users\mysql-test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parse
    r.js:80
            throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
            ^
    
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\mysql-
test\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_mo
dules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:130:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_mo
dules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_modules\mys
ql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_modules\m
ysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_modul
es\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_module
s\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_modul
es\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\mysql-test\node_modul
es\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mysql-test\server.js:
11:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
```

I've read up on some things such as:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1507

But I am still not sure how to fix my problem.

Comment: All VS Code users who use SQLTools extension should refer to this post in case they are having trouble with this, especially if you just upgraded a mysql instance on your development computer

Comment: I had the same issue because I used port 3306 when connecting but when I've installed MySQL I set the default port on 3307. So be careful, it could also be a protocol mismatch.

Comment: You should consider changing the accepted answer to Aidin's.

Comment: MySQL version 8 is not yet supported by Strapi. There is however an [official blog post](https://strapi.io/blog/configuring-strapi-mysql-database) to help you configure MySQL version 8 with Strapi.

Comment: Just update your npm package to `mysql2` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2). More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74458804/3944673) SO answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77785038/12836822

Answer (score 1867, accepted):

Execute the following query in MYSQL Workbench

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

Where `root` as your user
`localhost` as your URL
and `password` as your password

Then run this query to refresh privileges:

`flush privileges;`

Try connecting using node after you do so.

If that doesn't work, try it without `@'localhost'` part.

Comment: It worked for me without the @localhost (i guess it could be because it was not for the root user)

Comment: can not login with root after this. The password is not accepted anymore..

Comment: replace 'password' with your root password if you know it

Comment: It works...... but why it was not working before and why it worked after this query is still a question.

Comment: Hey people! Can someone go in depth of what is going on here? Why changing the native user would make such error go away?

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeMatuella 

This is because `caching_sha2_password` is introduced in MySQL 8.0, but the Node.js version is not implemented yet.

Comment: It works for me without the `@'localhost'` for me, anyone minds to explain on this?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella Please see my answer below for a detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065/2321594

Comment: Works for me only if I omit the @hostname part. If I include the hostname it doesn't work.

Comment: don't forget to restart node or pm2 process after u do this

Comment: The script doesn't execute if I remove the @'localhost' part. When I try to connect, the error I get says 'Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: @Shafique this guide worked for me like a charm: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.  I use Windows, so I follow this section: B.4.3.2.1 Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems

Comment: If I remove the @'localhost' portion, i get the following error: "Error Code: 1396. Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'%'"

Comment: THIS does not work MySql tells me that there is an Error around BY so the command is typed wrong I guess

Comment: don't skip on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065/3517025) answer below

Comment: i have to  try it without @'localhost' part, otherwiise it wont work

Comment: I ran this in terminal, dont have to remove localhost part.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella for the details on how this solution works and why is this NOT recommended in a production environment, see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065

Comment: Can you tell me how this is works?

Comment: worked without @localhost part at docker mysql:latest images

Comment: How to solve the same problem but with SQL Server Instead?

Comment: Worked for me by only triggering the command 'flush privileges;'

Comment: you just locked me out of everything with these commands. thanks

Comment: ALTER USER 'root' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
(in my case -> user: root, pass: ' ')

Comment: It worked for me without the '@localhost' part! Thanks for helping!

Comment: this leads to another error internal assertion for me

Answer (score 753):

### Summary

1. If you just want to get rid of the error, **at the cost of risking the security of the project** (e.g. it's just a personal project or dev environment), go with [@Pras's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831) -- `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'` and then `flush privileges`
2. If you want to have a fix for it, without knowing why, just install and use `mysql2` (instead of `mysql`) and use it -- `npm i mysql2`, and `mysql = require('mysql2');`.
3. If you are a curious developer who is always eager to learn, keep reading ... :)

---

### What's going on?

Let's first make it clear what's going on.

MySQL 8 has supports pluggable authentication methods.  By default, one of them named `caching_sha2_password` is used rather than our good old `mysql_native_password` ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html)). It should be obvious that using a crypto algorithm with several handshakes is more secure than plain password passing that has been there for [24 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)!

Now, the problem is `mysqljs` in Node (the package you install with `npm i mysql` and use it in your Node code) doesn't support this new default authentication method of MySQL 8, yet.  The issue is in here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1507 and is still open, after 3 years, as of July 2019.

**UPDATE June 2019:** There is a [new PR in mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/2233) now to fix this!

**UPDATE Feb 2020:** Apparently it's [scheduled to come in version 3 of mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/2233#issuecomment-578347577).

**UPDATE July 2020:** Apparently it's still not in [yet (as of April 2020 at least)](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2333), but it's [claimed](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2333#issuecomment-614696076) that [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) is supporting [Authentication switch request](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Authentication-Switch.md).  Please comment below if [`node-mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) is working fine for this issue -- I will test it later myself.

**UPDATE April 2021:** It seems like the issue is still there and just 3 days ago, [someone created a fork](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/2233#issuecomment-821285763) and made it there -- yet not official in the mysql.js package.  Also, as per the comments below, it seems like [mysql2 package](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) is working fine and [supporting Authentication-switch](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Authentication-Switch.md) properly.

---

## Your Current Options

#### Option 1) [NOT RECOMMENDED] Downgrade "MySQL" to authenticate using good old "mysql_native_password"

That's what everybody suggests here (e.g. [top answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831/2321594)). You just get into `mysql` and run a query saying `root` is fine using old `mysql_native_password` method for authentication:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password ...
```

The good thing is, life is going to be simple and you can still use good old tools like Sequel Pro without [any issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179516/sequel-pro-and-mysql-connection-failed/).  But the problem is, you are not taking advantage of a more secure (and cool, read below) stuffs available to you.

#### Option 2) [Meh...] Replace "Node" package with MySQL Connecter X DevAPI

[MySQL X DevAPI for Node](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/) is a replacement to [Node's Mysqljs package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), provided by http://dev.mysql.com official guys.

It works like a charm supporting `caching_sha2_password` authentication. (Just make sure you use port `33060` for [X Protocol communications](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html).)

The bad thing is, you have left our old `mysql` package that everyone is so used to and relies on.

The good thing is, your app is more secure now and you can take advantage of a ton of new things that our good old friends didn't provide!  Just check out the [tutorial of X DevAPI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/tutorial-Working_with_Collections.html) and you'll see it has a ton of new sexy features that can come in handy.  You just need to pay the price of a learning curve, which expectedly comes with any technology upgrade. :)

PS. Unfortunately, this XDevAPI Package doesn't have types definition (understandable by TypeScript) yet, so if you are on **typescript**, you will have problems.  I tried to generate .d.ts using `dts-gen` and `dtsmake`, but no success.  So keep that in mind.

#### Option 3) [RECOMMENDED] Replace "mysql.js" with "mysql2.js" package

As mentioned above, mysql package ([NPM package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)) is [still having this issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/2233) (as of April 2021).  But mysql2 package ([NPM package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)) is not.  So probably the following should be the one-liner answer!

```bash
npm un mysql && npm i mysql2
```

Please note that `mysql2` is a forked work off of the popular `mysql`, but its popularity (620K downloads per week for `mysql2` in April 2020) has got close to the original package (720K download per week for `mysql` in April 2021) that making the switch seems reasonable!

Comment: nice, an answer that actually explains mysql_native_password instead of just telling you to do it

Comment: Yes, a proper explanation for once. Good on you Aidin. How I wish connecting apps did not automatically configure port 3306 to MySQL. We have enough trouble prising MySQL and MariaDB away from 3306.

Comment: Be careful of Oracle plugins, you might get a big penalty: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/04/oracle_virtualbox_merula/

Comment: Does not work for me :( User is identified with mysql_native_password, php connector works ok, nodejs - fails with ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE :(

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would you recommend option 2 to be used for new node projects?

Comment: @emen, If you are not comfortable with reading the library code (in lieu of proper documentation), or you need to bring in Typescript, or security is NOT a life-threatening issue for your project, then No, don't go with option #2. :)

Comment: MySQL X DevAPI for Node is not a supported driver with knex.js fwiw

Comment: `node-mysql2` still doesn't support it but they are working on it as of 11-28-20... - https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1248

Comment: Incorrect. It's `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'`

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa, are you sure you read the answer?  I have written, in detail, why the `ALTER USER ...` solutions are "bad".   I guess you have just attempted to copy/paste the SQL line (ending with `...`) and because it doesn't work, obviously, you are saying this answer is "incorrect"? :)

Comment: My phrasing was not correct and the message did not went through, sorry @Aidin :) I said the command was incomplete because I used it on a small PoC I imported from somewhere else, and it wasn't working because there were missing characters (namely the`BY 'password'`) that you replaced by the ellipsis :)

Comment: Very nice explanation.  Helped a lot in solving problem in connecting to MySql from NodeJs.

Comment: After doing this I can't log in from the terminal anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65837402/3310334

Comment: @minseong You are having a problem with the solution that I have said "is Bad!".  I don't think you should have commented under this solution, unless, again, you take Stackoverflow answers like https://pics.me.me/my-eyes-on-stackoverflow-17-it-as-getlientokens-nosuch-refresh-token-1-then-function-tokens-61976976.png ;)

Comment: @Aidin your answer is great and I've upvoted it now, unfortunately it's buried by the lazy answer above and lazy (now regretful) me just copy/pasted from top answer. I wish I had seen yours first. Anyway I post my question to you because you seem to have a far better understanding of this area of mysql, so I just have my fingers crossed

Comment: `mysql2` solved the problem gracefully. I think this is the most proper solution.

Comment: @Stalinko thanks for verifying it.  I added it as the third solution (recommended).

Comment: still getting the same error with mysql2

Comment: Great answer! Still, don't forget to check the credentials...

Comment: Let me add a few rumblings here. What an amazing story with the patch. May people not be so lazy. May not their only wait for an author to take in action, but do something themselves. The authors may get distracted with their lives and other stuff. It's opensource after all.

Comment: I was battling with this problem, and I actually changed the entrypoint on my docker container so that I could manually troubleshoot the connection.  I  wrote a little node app using knex and mysql2 and it connected from the same container without a hassle.  So I knew it was something to do with the app I'm trying to run.  Thanks to you I now know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I tried installing mysql2 in my project directory, but npm gave me following error: $ npm i mysql2  npm ERR! code UNKNOWN  npm ERR! syscall symlink  npm ERR! path X:\<path-to-directory>\knex.js  npm ERR! dest X:\<path-to-directory>\node_modules\knexfile  npm ERR! errno -4094   npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, symlink 'X:\<path-to-directory>\knex.js' -> 'X:\<path-to-directory>\node_modules\knexfile' --> <path-to-directory> is some path to my project ;) Anyone an idea how to solve? The directory has no symlink knex.js

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it explains root of the problem and gives solutions with explanations. Thank you very much Aidin

Comment: I think I solved the problem with this, the error is gone, but now I cannot connect to db because of some username issue. Everything is imported just fine from the .env file to the .config file, except the username: mysql2 will try to connect with the username of the PC's (at least it seems like that's the one) and not what I've defined in .env. Does somebody have an idea why?

Comment: later edit: I didn't know, and had to find the hard way: process.env.USER translates to username of machine. I've changed to DB_USER and now it's working fine.

Comment: FYI, the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js contains the proper TypeScript type definitions for the whole API since v8.0.30.

Comment: Issue still persists as of `6 July 2023`.

Answer (score 114):

Using the old `mysql_native_password` works:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YourRootPassword';
-- or
CREATE USER 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'bar';
-- then
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This is because `caching_sha2_password` is introduced in MySQL 8.0, but the Node.js version is not implemented yet. You can see [this pull request](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/1962) and [this issue](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/820) for more information. Probably a fix will come soon!

Comment: whats the difference between adding @localhost and just 'root'

Comment: Query works. But still node couldn't connect to the MySQL server. Any idea?

Here's the error,

{
  "code": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR",
  "errno": 1045,
  "sqlMessage": "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
  "sqlState": "28000",
  "fatal": true
}

Answer (score 53):

## Full Steps For MySQL 8

### Connect to MySQL

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: (enter your root password)
```

### Reset your password

(Replace `your_new_password` with the password you want to use)

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Then try connecting using node

Comment: @sky see my answer above for the details.

Comment: I prefer this direct method as opposed to swimming around the confusing Mysql Workbench wondering where/if commands are actually running.

Comment: This solution worked for me except without the @'localhost'.

Answer (score 27):

Although the accepted answer is correct, I'd prefer creating a new user and then using that user to access the database.

```
create user nodeuser@localhost identified by 'nodeuser@1234';
grant all privileges on node.* to nodeuser@localhost;
ALTER USER 'nodeuser'@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'nodeuser@1234';
```

Comment: If someone wants to go this route, here's an article with some explanation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: Siddhant would "prefer", but I was "required" to do this. IMO, this makes this answer required reading!

Comment: for me the given priveleges were not enough to create a DB. i gave `grant all privileges on *.* to nodeuser@localhost;`

Comment: I think the use of grant privileges here worked well with me.                                           I can advise someone to use this answer.

Comment: What exactly is that 'nodeuser@1234' supposed to be? A new password? Why do we need that?

Comment: @sander I just cleaned the code to make it easier to understand (if it will be approved):

```
CREATE USER 'nodeuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'somePassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON node.* TO 'nodeuser'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 26):

If you ran into this issue but continued to wish to utilise version 8 of `MySQL`, you can. When creating the database using `Docker`, you can accomplish this by instructing MySQL Server to implement the legacy authentication plugin.

Thus, your `compose` file will appear as follows:

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials

version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.15
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass'
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
       MYSQL_USER: 'user'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pass'
    ports:
      - 3318:3306
    # Change this to your local path
    volumes:
      - ~/Database/ORM_Test:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I'm using this `command`, but still getting the unsupported authentication error message when using `mysql` in Node.js

Comment: The full stacktrace is here: https://pastebin.com/SzayQzdh and the **docker-compose.yml**: https://pastebin.com/7pUrWYDs The error itself is: `Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`

Comment: @JuhaUntinen make sure that you removed a Docker container (the one created by docker-compose) and volume (~/Database/ORM_Test) and then run 'docker-compose up' again. Otherwise the changes from 'command' won't be applied. It helped in my case.

Comment: The command has to be set in docker-compose BEFORE the user is made. If you are using MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD, you'll have to wipe out /var/lib/mysql and start from scratch so command is set before creating the user, or fallback to one of the other answers and ALTER the already created user

Comment: @VitaliiIvanov Exactly. This can be accomplished by `docker-compose down --volumes && docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 23):

Simplest answer is :-

1. Use mysql2 instead of mysql in node

install mysql2 in node

2. **npm install mysql2**

Don't downgrade your mysql db.

You are good to go.
**Happy Coding!**

Comment: dont forget to change to mysql2 in require

Comment: I get the result as [object Object],[object Object][object Object]....

What could cause this?

Comment: Found the solution. It retrieves the object, so that I have to read it by line and column.

Answer (score 20):

If the ALTER USER ... command line doesn't work for you AND if you are using Windows 10 then try to follow those steps:

1) Type MySQL in the windows search bar

2) Open the MySQL Windows Installer - Community

3) Look for "MySQL server" and click on Reconfigure
[image: step 3]

4) Click on "Next" until you reach the "Authentification Method" phase

5) On the "Authentification Method" phase check the second option "Use Legacy Authentication Method"
[image: step 5]

6) Then follow the steps given by the Windows installer until the end

7) When it's done, go into "Services" from the Windows search bar, click on "start" MySql81".

Now, try again, the connection between MySQL and Node.js should work!

Comment: This solution solved my problem.  My code was fine, just the authentication on my Windows 10 machine was the issue.

Answer (score 16):

The cleanest solution is to do the below command, and this issue will go away:

```bash
npm uninstall mysql
npm install mysql2
```

And then use it normally in your code:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql2');
    
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "password"
});
    
con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I did not have any MySQL client in my system, but my `docker container` had an image, which was giving me this issue. Simply installing the `mysql2` resolved the issue.

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2390#issuecomment-758888705) as well, mentioned in the official `mysql` npm packages issues' answers. All the best.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! I'm still stuggling to make everything work with Docker, but that's another problem.

Answer (score 14):

In Mysql Latest docker container

```
ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: WARNING: This will make your database less secure

Answer (score 8):

Downgrading might not be a good option as:

1. Its upgraded for a reason (To provide better authentication).
2. You might not have enough permissions to make such changes.

You can use `mysql2` package in place of `mysql`. Its mostly API compatible with mysqljs.
Also, it has promises support.

Use it like:
`const mysql = require('mysql2/promise')` (for promise based methods)

You can read more about `mysql2` here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Comment: I just use mysql2! `const mysql = require('mysql2')`. It works! Thanks a lot

Comment: Dang, I might've created `prettyquery` for promise support for nothing :o

Answer (score 8):

For MySql 8 instead of changing the authentication for the **root** user create a new **user** with all privileges and change the authentication method from caching_sha2_password to mysql_native_password.
Please check the [documentation](https://medium.com/@kelvinekrresa/mysql-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-6eed9a6e813e) by Ochuko Ekrresa for detailed steps.

Summary of Steps:

1. Login as root  `mysql -u root -p`
2. Create new user `CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
3. Grand all permission `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';`

Check the above-mentioned document link to get details on giving specific privileges.

4. Reload the privileges `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. Quit MySql `quit;` and login again with `mysql -u [newuser] -p;`
6. Last step change the authentication `ALTER USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'password';`

Additional Info:
For me after changing authentication for root, I was faced with Authentication issues and was unable to login. So I reset my password([Reset password doc](https://gist.github.com/kpssachin/0337daa7f7493717acf683f59d4c203b)).

Answer (score 7):

> In MySQL 8.0, `caching_sha2_password` is the default authentication
>   plugin rather than `mysql_native_password. ...`

Most of the answers in this question result in a downgrade to the authentication mechanism from `caching_sha2_password` to `mysql_native_password`. From a security perspective, this is quite disappointing.

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html) document extensively discusses `caching_sha2_password` and of course why it should NOT be a first choice to downgrade the authentication method.

With that, I believe Aidin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065/10637968) should be the accepted answer. Instead of downgrading the authentication method, use a [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/) which matches the server's version instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using docker, it worked for me!

in the `docker-compose.yml` add the following lines:

```
mysql:
   ...    
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   restart: always
```

after that, `down` the container and `up` again.

Answer (score 5):

For existing mysql 8.0 installs on Windows 10 mysql,

1. launch installer,
2. click "Reconfigure" under QuickAction (to the left of MySQL Server), then
3. click next to advance through the next 2 screens until arriving
4. at "Authentication Method", select "Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x compatibility"
5. Keep clicking until install is complete

Comment: Aren't we trying to have the most recent, since it is more secure?

Comment: Of course we should, but sometimes it requires re-writing parts of the code that the client/boss/specs insist should be untouched, or we're just lazy and don't want to patch the authentication code when it's tangential to the project or in someone else's scope...

Answer (score 5):

> simple i **uninstall mysql** and **install mysql2** for this issues and
> problem solved.

```
npm uninstall mysql && npm i mysql2
```

Answer (score 4):

Original documentation you can find here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/

```
'use strict';

const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

const options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 33060,
  password: '******',
  user: 'root',
  schema: 'yourconference'
};

mysqlx.getSession(options)
  .then(session => {
          console.log(session.inspect());
           session.close();
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: It looks more complicated, but I think we should follow the official guide! b

Answer (score 4):

I have MYSQL on server and nodejs application on another server

Execute the following query in MYSQL Workbench

ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

Answer (score 4):

With MySQL 8+ the new default authentication is `caching_sha2_password` instead of `mysql_native_password`. The new and more secure authentication method is not supported by the native `mysql` package yet, but you should consider using the package `@mysql/xdevapi` instead, which is officially supported and maintained by Oracle.

To install the new package, run:

```
npm install @mysql/xdevapi --save --save-exact
```

To connect to the database and INSERT some VALUES:

```
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
var myTable;

mysqlx
    .getSession({
        user: 'root',
        password: '*****',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 33060
    })
    .then(function (session) {

    // Accessing an existing table
    myTable = session.getSchema('Database_Name').getTable('Table_Name');

    // Insert SQL Table data
    return myTable
        .insert(['first_name', 'last_name'])
        .values(['John', 'Doe'])
        .execute()
    });
```

The official package documentation can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers ;
After executing the below command

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

If you get an error as :

```
[ERROR] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 42, found 44. The table is probably corrupted
```

Then try in the cmd as admin; set the path to MySQL server bin folder in the cmd

```
set path=%PATH%;D:\xampp\mysql\bin;
```

and then run the command :

```
mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

This should update the server and the system tables.

Then you should be able to successfully run the below commands in a Query in the Workbench :

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

then remember to execute the following command:

```
flush privileges;
```

After all these steps should be able to successfully connect to your MySQL database.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

I just run into this problem too, with all the MySQL re-config mentioned above the error still appears. It turns out that I **misspelled the database name**.

So be sure you're connecting with the right database name especially the case.

Answer (score 2):

### I would recommend to use [**Knexjs**](http://knexjs.org/) with [**MySQL2**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).

And you have good to go with `caching_sha2_password` auth method.

**Query with Knex:**

```
const response = await knex.raw("SELECT * FROM USERS");
```

**OR**

If you don't have a remote user then use `CREATE` keyword instead of `ALTER` and just put the below command on the terminal.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
Flush privileges;

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
Flush privileges;
```

**All done :)**

Answer (score 0):

Check privileges and username/password for your MySQL user.

For catching errors it is always useful to use overrided `_delegateError` method. In your case this has to look like:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  insecureAuth : true
});

var _delegateError = con._protocol._delegateError;

con._protocol._delegateError = function(err, sequence) {
    if (err.fatal)
        console.trace('MySQL fatal error: ' + err.message);

    return _delegateError.call(this, err, sequence);
};

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

This construction will help you to trace fatal errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out after trying numerous things. What finally did it for me was adding `require('dotenv').config()` to my `.sequelizerc` file. Apparently sequelize-cli doesn't read env variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the ORM, builders, etc. and simplify your DB/SQL management using [`sqler`](https://ugate.github.io/sqler/) and [`sqler-mdb`](https://ugate.github.io/sqler-mdb/tutorial-2-usage.html#examples).

```sql
-- create this file at: db/mdb/read.table.rows.sql
SELECT TST.ID AS "id", TST.NAME AS "name", NULL AS "report",
TST.CREATED_AT AS "created", TST.UPDATED_AT AS "updated"
FROM TEST TST
WHERE UPPER(TST.NAME) LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', UPPER(:name)), '%')
```

```js
const conf = {
  "univ": {
    "db": {
      "mdb": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "username":"admin",
        "password": "mysqlpassword"
      }
    }
  },
  "db": {
    "dialects": {
      "mdb": "sqler-mdb"
    },
    "connections": [
      {
        "id": "mdb",
        "name": "mdb",
        "dir": "db/mdb",
        "service": "MySQL",
        "dialect": "mdb",
        "pool": {},
        "driverOptions": {
          "connection": {
            "multipleStatements": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

// create/initialize manager
const manager = new Manager(conf);
await manager.init();

// .sql file path is path to db function
const result = await manager.db.mdb.read.table.rows({
  binds: {
    name: 'Some Name'
  }
});

console.log('Result:', result);

// after we're done using the manager we should close it
process.on('SIGINT', async function sigintDB() {
  await manager.close();
  console.log('Manager has been closed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error for several hours an just got to the bottom of it, finally. As Zchary says, check very carefully you're passing in the right database name.

Actually, in my case, it was even worse: I was passing in *all* my `createConnection()` parameters as `undefined` because I was picking them up from `process.env`. Or so I thought! Then I realised my debug and test npm scripts worked but things failed for a normal run. Hmm...

So the point is - MySQL seems to throw this error even when the username, password, database and host fields are all `undefined`, which is slightly misleading..

Anyway, morale of the story - check the silly and seemingly-unlikely things first!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to create a new user privilege then do so to connect normally with node.js, that is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MY_NEW_PASSWORD')
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Mac OS, and would like to use the legacy password encryption without using terminal.

Go to System Settings -> Find "My SQL" -> Click "Initialize Database" -> Select "Use legacy password encryption" and enter your database user password in the textfield and click "Ok"

Answer (score 0):

in case you come accross this question and your stuff is at Digitalocean:

You can add a legacy user using MySQL 5+ encryption

1. Select your Database / Cluster
2. Click "Users & Databases"
3. Enter a username and select the proper encryption

Voilá

Answer (score 0):

For my case just changing the driver class name  in configuration

> from  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

works for me .

Answer (score 0):

Create a user with permissions DBA

Answer (score -1):

Just Run MySQL Server Installer and Reconfigure the My SQL Server...This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

you should use whatever schema you use for your mysql connection for your session

```
(async () => {
    const connection = await db.connection();
    sessionStore = new MySQLStore({

    }, connection); //just pass your connection here 
})();
```

I just copy paste this here but your probably have implemented something similar to this to deal with your queries

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const dbConfig = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    connectionLimit: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_LIMITS
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);

const connection = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            const query = (sql, binding) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    connection.query(sql, binding, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve(result);
                    });
                });
            };

            const release = () => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(connection.release());
                });
            };
            resolve({ query, release });
        });
    });
};

const query = (sql, binding) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(sql, binding, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = { pool, connection, query };
```

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem with MySQL and I solve by using XAMPP to connect with MySQL and stop the services in windows for MySQL (control panel - Administrative Tools - Services), and in the folder db.js (that responsible for the database ) I make the password empty (here you can see:)

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: ''
});
```

Comment: please don't add a issue that you are facing as a answer to the problem faced

Comment: And also do not use `root` to connect to your databases. Create another user, grant the permissions you need it to have, than use it!