# Access MySQL-DB (on plesk server) via Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh, plesk

I just purchased my own domain including webhosting on a plesk server.
Fortunately they also provide a MySQL database. Accessing the DB via the MySQL workbench (locally) works just fine when I insert my credentials (for some reason the only working connection method is 'Standard TCP/IP over SSH'(and it does not even need a location for a privatekey)), but I couldn't find a way to make this work using node.js. (I am using Version 8.11.1).

I decided to use node.js since I want to make some interactive data visualizations with d3 and since I have almost 40000 datapoints I would like to outsource as many processes to the server as possible.

Of course I want to try everything locally as well as on the server.

According to the connection method I used with the workbench, I suspect to use some ssh-modules (just using mysql  module won't work either). For now I tried these:

1. mysql-ssh (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-ssh)

   Just putting my credentials (including the privatekey) into the example code just returns this error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: All configured authentication methods failed
    at tryNextAuth (C:\Users\matth\git\soundstats_elak_titles\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:380:17)
    at SSH2Stream.onUSERAUTH_FAILURE (C:\Users\matth\git\soundstats_elak_titles\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:591:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at SSH2Stream.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at parsePacket (C:\Users\matth\git\soundstats_elak_titles\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:3929:10)
    at SSH2Stream._transform (C:\Users\matth\git\soundstats_elak_titles\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:669:13)
    at SSH2Stream.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:186:10)
    at SSH2Stream._read (C:\Users\matth\git\soundstats_elak_titles\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:251:15)
    at SSH2Stream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:174:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:397:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

from my unsertanding the first block within `mysqlssh.connect` is equivalent to the fields in mysql workbench connection configurations SSH Hostname and SSH Username,
while the second block is equivalent to MySQL Hostname and Username

2. msql2 & ssh2 (as described on https://medium.com/@devontem/nodejs-express-using-ssh-to-access-mysql-remotely-60372832dd08)

Inserting credentials into this example I first got these messages

```
(node:6548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: null
(node:6548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and after waiting for several minutes, the program ends with this message:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:628:25)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

here the order of the credential blocks seem to be switched compared to mysql-ssh

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing any relevant code...

Comment: I used the code as used in the links I posted. Just replaced the credentials as described. Please understand, that I do not want to post any usernames, ips or passwords

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mysql-ssh is using node-mysql2 under the hood, which currently does not support the new default authentication plugin used by MySQL 8.0.

Additional details are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377944/3235909).