# Why is my Node.js code working when xampp is running mysql, but not when mysql notifier has mysql server running?

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

I am new to using node.js and mysql, I have a simple script that uses node to log me into a mysql server.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : ''
});
connection.connect(function(err) 
{
  if (!err)
    console.log('Connected');
  else
    console.log('Error connection');
    console.log(err);
});
```

When my xampp mysql server is running it returns connected, however when xampp is turned off and the mysql server notifier is running it returns this error.

"*code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true }*"
I used the installer for windows found on the mysql site. I am running windows 10, and it is installed directly into the C drive of my computer.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you try by executing following command:

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what was MySQL Notifier so I searched on Google. According to the documentation I found [here (www.mysql.com)](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/notifier/), MySQL Notifier only notifies for changes on your system and connection to your MySQL Server.

It means that this utility tool **is not** a MySQL server, you can't use it like it was. You need a running MySQL server (launched by xamp).

There are many ways to run a MySQL server without xamp:

- Like you did: with the standalone MySQL Community Server on your Windows: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
- With Docker, if you're familiar with: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Anyway, your server version mismatches with your client version, which is here your `mysql` Node.js library. The two versions work with each other but the authentication method seems to have changed.

Which version of it do you use? Did you try to update it? `npm update mysql`

**Best solution maybe here:** There is a closed issue on this subject in the [`mysqljs` GitHub repository](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) where Andrey Sidorov advices to

> allow to use insecure auth: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options `insecureAuth` option.
>
> Source: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1574

Option description:

> - insecureAuth: Allow connecting to MySQL instances that ask for the old (insecure) authentication method. (Default: false)
>
> https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options

You can try to set this option to `true`:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  insecureAuth: true
});
```

Just a little thing, "xamp" stands for "LinuX Apache MySQL PHP" (so you're using "wamp" -> "Windows Apache MySQL PHP").

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0 then you are probably facing the same issue (and will be able to solve it with the same solution) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0/50377944#50377944).