# "Client does not support authentication protocol"-error fixed but causes an error with adminer

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, docker

I started a project on another computer using docker, node, sequelize, adminer and mysql. Then I got a new computer and downloaded the project but when trying to start the project on the new computer I got the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

This error only affects a specific part of the project and not the part with adminer which in this state works fine. I can log in to it and see the database created with docker. I then solve the error with the following code:

```
docker exec -it ticketgo_database_1 bash

mysql --user=root --password

ALTER USER 'root' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ‘pass’;
```

Now that specific part of the code works but when i try to log in to Adminer I get the following error:

```
mysql has gone away
```

It most certainly has to do with the fix to the first error but I'm really not sure why?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I was not able to find the RAM size of my MYSQL host server. I am not using a my.cnf/my.ini configuration file so the settings should be default.

Comment: Here is the Global status and the global variables: https://pastebin.com/befxFQfu

Comment: I am not using the MySQLTuner so i do not have a report

Comment: Mysqltuner report is handy and helps verify info.  We can get along without it.  RAM will be in the following, if you could post them for me.  Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, for server tuning analysis.  Thanks for the GS and GV already posted.

Comment: And, Please also post last 400 lines of error log when back on line AFTER Adminer causes MySQL has gone away. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the help. Where do I find the error log? When I try to log in through adminer the terminal window only displays 2-3 lines of code. And FYI i'm on a OS system

Comment: What's the MySQL version?

Comment: I'm using mysql  Ver 8.0.12

Comment: The node.js-related issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0/50377944#50377944). I have no idea about the Adminer issue though. Details are pretty vague.

Comment: I'm using macOS

Comment: Processor: 2,6 GHz intel core i5, 8GB RAM and No SSD or NVME storage that I'm aware of

Comment: @oscar  Just found this SO question / answer.  It may applicable for your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051923/consider-upgrading-mysql-client-at-handshake-sequence-packettoerror

If you are still stymied in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section (RPS = Rate Per Second)

```
# 20180828 0707 from mysqlservertuning.com
# log_error=/var/lib/mysql/2cd908c24352-error.log  # from default of stderr, for log
# max_connect_errors=10  # from 100 - why give a cracker/hacker more than 10 shots?
# thread_cache_size=32  # from 9 for thread breathing room
# innodb_io_capacity=2000  # from 200 to allow more IOPS
# expire_logs_days=10  # from 0 for limited historical logs
# general_log=1  # from OFF until you get a handle on Adminer failure!!!

#    IN ANY CASE 10 Minutes after START of INSTANCE, 
# SET GLOBAL general_log=0 to avoid filling your storage media completely full.

# innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct=90  # from 25 percent for more WARM cache at start
# innodb_page_cleaners=2  # from 1 to expedite page clean operations
# open_files_limit=30000  # from 1 million for a more reasonable upper limit
# slow_query_log=1  # from OFF should be ON for detection, prevention, if possible
```

Each DAY, save your current my.ini in \history with DATED timed filename such as 20180827hhmm-my.cnf to allow going back to last working my.ini quickly.

Copy this BLOCK (including the leading date and our web site name)to END of your [mysqld] section and ENABLE one change per DAY by removing leading # and spacecharacter, monitor before moving on to next change.

Disable EARLIER same NAMED variable with leading # and space bar, to avoid confusion. In 5 years you will still have history of my.ini changes with approximate dates.

Normally only ONE change per day, monitor before moving to next change. If a change seems detrimental, go back to last working my.ini and let us know, please.

In your situation, I would enable ALL the suggestions.  It is not like you are in production - yet.

For additional suggestions (and you have many more opportunities) please view profile, Network profile, for contact information including my Skype ID.

Comment: @Oscar Wondering if any suggestions have been implemented?  Positive influence in response time?  Determined why Adminer stops instance?  If no progress on this detail, please post General Log from start to stop of instance for no charge analysis, please.