# Consider upgrading MySQL client at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError

Tags: mysql

I am learning expressjs and connecting to MySQL database, but getting below error.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'Damodars-MacBook-pro.local',
  user     : 'monty',
  password : 'some_pass',
  port     : 3306,
});

connection.query('USE angularapp');
// Routing
// Configure port
app.set('port', 3006);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Getting error as:

> Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support
>   authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client
>       at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError

Comment: What is the version of your MySQL server and of the `node-mysql` library in your installation?

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn MySQL 8.0.12 , please let me know how to find node-mysql library version, on running node -v, it shows as v8.11.3

Comment: Run `npm list mysql` in your project directory

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn damodar@1.0.0 /Users/Damodar
└── mysql@2.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the `node-mysql` github repo, MySQL 8.0 is currently not supported.  There is [an open pull request](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/1962) to add the support.

Until a fix is released, I would recommend to install MySQL 5.7 instead of MySQL 8.0.

You can also try installing the Node library `mysql2` instead of `mysql`, but I am not sure whether it supports MySQL 8.0.

Comment: can i down grad mysql on the MySQL 8.0 or uninstall n install?

Comment: @developer I am not sure how exactly it is done on macOS, but most probably you'll need to uninstall and install