# Installing older version of MySQL brew error

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, homebrew, sha2

I'm a little frustrated at this point, so I had to come for aid to stackoverflow lol I've been stuck trying to setup the dev environment for 3h...

This is what's happening, the new version of mysql doesn't support compatible client-side authentication mechanisms for the new server plugin.
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0)

So at this point I had MySQL installed with version 8.0 and I'm trying to revert it back to 5.7 because none of my node.js projects work locally.

Now, I followed [this](https://soatechlab.blogspot.com/2011/01/completely-remove-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html) to uninstall MySQL completely.
and [this](https://gist.github.com/benlinton/d24471729ed6c2ace731) to install multi version with the difference of instead of writing mysql56 I wrote mysql@5.7 because `homebrew/versions/` is deprecated.

So... once I do that I go to the terminal and check:
`sudo mysql -v`
and I get this:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

That is if I remove the current agent (the new version 8.0), if I add it back:

```
# Start agent for current version of mysql (including on login)
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

then it would show me this:
[image]

The older version which is the one I want is already linked: 
`brew link --force mysql@5.7`

now... here is the funny thing, when I type: `mysql --version`
it says: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

And when I go to my node.js env. to run a query or something, it says:
`Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`
which is the problem mentioned on the other posts about MySQL versioning.

Can someone lend me a hand please. Thanks guys

Comment: ["MAC"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) refers to something specific, so please don't casually capitalize things that aren't meant to be capitalized. Programmers are trained to be especially case sensitive!

Comment: If you're downgrading you may need to nuke out your MySQL database directory or it can't boot as a 5.7 server can't read 8.0 data files. As always, check `mysql.err` for details. If you have any critical data in your database, please **back up first before proceeding**.

Comment: @tadman The database is empty, it's an empty DB of a project that I'm making from scratch. Btw what do you mean nuke out?

Comment: Clear out all the MySQL 8.0 data files and start over with 5.7.

Comment: I'm trying that approach and another one, I'll let you know if it works :)

Comment: I was able to get it going, I'll post the answer later I need a break... I knew it couldn't be so hard but that happens when you don't know... Thanks for the help @tadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brew was suppoused to give me a nice and quick way to install that version, but I ended up even forgeting what I was developing to troubleshoot MySQL... So I decided to go to the oracle page and download it from there. I made a guide, in case another person has the same problem, to read it go [here](https://elkepon.com/install-mysql-on-mac-os-to-work-with-node-js-auth/).

If someone has time and wants to have some fun with brew let me know what's the fix for that :)