# Unable to login to a mysql container in docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js

I'm trying to set up an application which has 1 node.js server and 1 mysql database. I'm trying to integrate this with docker. I'm having trouble trying to login to mysql from my node.js app.

in short - here's my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    restart: always
    environment:
      # - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=subscriptions
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
      - MYSQL_USER=root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 1


  subscription_api:
    build: ./subscription_api_server
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

My `Dockerfile` for mySQL

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS subscriptions;

grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'supersecretpassword' with grant option;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

My node.js application uses `sequelize` as the ORM and the connection string is specified here `config.js`

```
"development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "supersecretpassword",
    "database": "subscriptions",
    "host": "db",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
```

When i run `docker-compose up` - i get the below error from my `node.js` application

```
subscription_api_1  | Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.12.0, CLI: 5.1.0, ORM: 4.39.0]
subscription_api_1  | 
subscription_api_1  | Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
subscription_api_1  | Using environment "development".
subscription_api_1  | Sun, 14 Oct 2018 17:50:17 GMT sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators at node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13
subscription_api_1  | 
subscription_api_1  | ERROR: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

But the username/password work when i try to directly ssh into my docker container

```
sudo docker exec -it fullstack-dev-assignment_db_1 bash
root@d36f499b706e:/# mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@d36f499b706e:/# mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

Am i doing something wrong with the way `sequelize` is setup?

Comment: You grant all privileges to root on localhost, but nodejs app cannot connect it by localhost without exposing port in mysql container. Try adding ports mapping in db section.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are eventually pulling the `mysql:latest` docker image, which in this case would be from the 8.0 series. The problem is that MySQL 8.0 is now using a default authentication plugin that is incompatible with the community Node.js driver used by `sequelize`.

You should follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0/50377944#50377944) to overcome that limitation.

In your case, besides granting the privileges, you would have to first switch the user authentication plugin as well.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'supersecretpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```