# ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Problem in mysql used in nodejs**

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '123456789',
  database : 'userdata'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err);
    return;
  }

 console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

**Error**: **ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)

Comment: Right, if you are using MySQL 8.0 series, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373427/node-js-cant-authenticate-to-mysql-8-0/50377944#50377944) as well.

Comment: Prashant Gupta -- for me it working thank you so much man..

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Install **[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)**

Execute this query: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456789';` in MySQL Workbench

Head back over to Node.js and try running the file again. It should work, at least it did for me.

Comment: This query bars me to access DB even using WorkBench

Comment: I just ran this query and now I cannot even log into workbench

Comment: Don't use it on the root user then. Mostly it's never good to use the root user as an application user. Especially because creating a new user and granting it all privileges on one DB can be accomplished in two commands: `CREATE USER 'other_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456789'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON userdata.* TO 'other_user'@'localhost';`

Comment: Please note! This is decreasing security by using an older, weaker hashing algorithm for the password! This is not a good idea; instead the node library should be updated to support the new password hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 10):

## Best Solution try this it will resolve:

You installed mysql server using "mysql installer"

```
1)open -> "mysql intsaller"

2)press reconfig mysql server

3)select left side "authentication method tab"

4)select radio button -->use legacy authentication method

5)now stop and restart the db
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In any database software (mysql workbench,datagrip, dbeaver...):

First run this query:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Second, if your problem still persists, run this query:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Combining and running these two queries separately worked for me with dockorize mysql.

Comment: Running both statements sequentially worked!

Answer (score 1):

update node-version to 16.X or greater and
change the module from  '*mysql/sync-mysql*' to '**mysql2**' in node api file

Answer (score 1):

### Solution using PhpMyadmin

1. login on server as `root`
2. click "User accounts"
   [image]
3. Find user which You will use to login by client
4. Click "Change password"
   [image]
5. Type Your old password, then change `Password Hashing` to `Native MySQL authentication`
   [image]
6. Click "Go"
7. Password and auth method was changed. Now try use Your client.

Answer (score 0):

someone can tell me how this command works?

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35471719)