# how to fix the error of connecting database with nodejs in linux?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect mysql with nodejs, but there is a problem in my code, please help!

```
var express    = require("express");
 var mysql      = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : 'admin',
   database : 'dbname',
 });  
 var app = express();

 connection.connect(function(err){
 if(!err) {
     console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");  
 } else {
     console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");  
 }
 });
app.listen(3000);
```

in terminal i am getting this output:

voldemort@Lenovo:~/Documents/cloudprint$ node server.js
Error connecting database ...

Comment: Please provide the full error output. But probably you have to add port settings as well, check if your database port differs from the default 3306

Comment: It might help if you also displayed the actual error. The error messages usually give a lot of information and aren’t just a flag that an error happened.

Comment: add a `console.log(err))`. What does it say?

Comment: @molamk where do i add it?

Comment: before `console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");`

Comment: @molamk  now i am getting a big error.(not able to paste it completely)node server.js
{ Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/voldemort/Documents/cloudprint/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/voldemort/Documents/cloudprint/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:124:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.0, the issue and possible fixes are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377944/3235909).

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL client establishes a connection to the server using secure authentication by default.

> insecureAuth: Allow connecting to MySQL instances that ask for the old (insecure) authentication method. (Default: false) <sup>[1](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options)</sup>

Looking at the error traceback in your comment, it looks like your server isn't currently configured to allow secure authentication. <sup>[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-auth)</sup>

If your MySQL server version is `<= 5.6.4` then secure auth is off and you may want to enable the old auth protocol by enabling `insecureAuth` when making the connection in the client.

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : 'admin',
   database : 'dbname',
   insecureAuth: true
 });
```

> However, I advise updating the passwords for your users to use the more secure password hashing function if your MySQL server version is `>= 5.6.5`. 
>   There is [step-by-step documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-upgrades.html) to accomplish this for user accounts.

You may also want to update your MySQL server if you find that you're running an older version that doesn't support the secure auth protocol.