# Error: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

While executing a JDBC program, I get the following error while connecting to database:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does 
not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading 
MySQL client
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:921)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at 
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at main.java.MyFirstJdbcProgram.readDataBase(MyFirstJdbcProgram.java:23)
at main.java.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

When I researched this, I got to know that the below error is because I need to grant the privileges to the user, so follow

1. `mysql -u root -p`
2. then entered the password
3. then I ran

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
   ```

   and also I used

   ```
   UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('mypassword') WHERE user='root';
   ```

But I'm getting below error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'' at line 1

Comment: ya ya i upgraded by running                                                               C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin> mysql_upgrade -u root -p
Enter password: **********
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 8.0.11, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? Also, why do you think the error _"Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client"_ has anything to do with granting privileges to the user? What is your source for that idea?

Comment: i have used 8.0.11 , installed using MySql Installer

Comment: Is that the version of MySQL you use, or the version of MySQL Connector/J (the MySQL JDBC driver), because to me the error seems to indicate that you are using a relatively old MySQL Connector/J driver (that is 5.1.45 or earlier).

Comment: Thank u , u pointed out correctly , i was using old version of MySql Connector when replaced with the new version , it worked properly , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error occurs because you are using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.45 or earlier. MySQL 8 introduced a new authentication mechanism (`caching_sha2_password`) that is not supported in those versions of the driver.

You will need to upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46 or higher. The latest version of the MySQL Connector/J driver at time of writing is 8.0.15. You can download it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ or specify the right version in Maven/Gradle, etc.

Comment: hello, how can I update it? I have the same problem with an old program. I have to upgrade connector of it? How I can do that?

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri Either you need to update the maven (or gradle) dependencies of your application, or - if you don't use those tools - you will need to download it yourself from the MySQL site and replace your existing MySQL Connector/J library.

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing Jasper server with MySQL-8.
And you're getting above error OR 'Access denied for user root@localhost' while running **js-install-ce.bat** / **js-install-ce.bat test** .

1. Run mysql query:
   **SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;**

Check the plugin column for ‘root’ user, it has to be ‘mysql_native_password’. If the plugin value is ‘caching_sha2_password’ then you need to run update query:
**ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';**

**OR**

2. Re-Install MySQL.
   You just have to re-install MySQL-8 with Authentication Method as:
   "**Use Legacy Authentication Method(Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility)**", as given in snapshot:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOFfS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Run:

`export MYSQL_PW='your_password'`
in your environment and use 'process.env.MYSQL_PW' as your password in the code below.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',  //your root username 
  database : 'your_database',   //the name of your db (create this if you haven't already)
  password : process.env.MYSQL_PW   //your root user's password
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MySQL 8.0.17 or greater than 5.7 version? uninstall this version because this version using SSH password-encryption that's why our database password they could not take. Install version 5.6 or 5.5 then it is working fine or you understand very well what the issue or what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you try connect to a different version of mysql connector which is a newer version and it requires some security check up and stuff, but all of these are not competible with your project you are running.

So this is what i did :

1. Open Mysql Installer :
   [image]
2. Click reconfigure
3. Click next
4. Read this instructions and select this :
   [image]

5) Enter your root password, Next and Execute.
6) Now try redeploy or whatever.

Thought it will be useful