# Docker Flyway MySQL 8 : Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. Consider upgrading MariaDB client

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose, flyway

I am running my application in docker container where flyway migration tool gives error while connecting to MySQL DB (8.0.11) :
Here is the complete error:

```
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306) for user 'deepti': 
Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. 
Consider upgrading MariaDB client. plugin was = caching_sha2_password
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services: 
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.11
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=...
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test1
      - MYSQL_USER=...
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=...

  flyway-service-i:
    image: boxfuse/flyway
    command: -url=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306 -schemas=test1 -user=... -password=... migrate
    volumes:
     - "../resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql"
    depends_on:
     - docker-mysql 

  spring-boot-jpa-docker-webapp:
    image: deepti/spring-boot-docker
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=docker-mysql
      - DATABASE_USER=...
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=...
      - DATABASE_NAME=test1 
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424900/error-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server-cons

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default authentication method in MySQL changed to `caching_sha2_password` in [version 8.0.4](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/). It doesn't look like the [MariaDB connector supports it](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONC-312?jql=text%20~%20%22caching_sha2_password%22).

You can revert the [default authentication plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin) to the old version by adding the `command` shown below:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.11
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
...
```

For any existing users in the db that have already been created with the `caching_sha2_password` authentication method, you can alter the user to use `mysql_native_password`:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'ip_address' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Or just remove the existing container with `docker-compose rm`.

I have created a working example in [this repository](https://github.com/andyrbell/mysql8-authentication). Here is the successful output:

```
Flyway Community Edition 5.1.4 by Boxfuse

Database: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/test1 (MySQL 8.0)
WARNING: You are connected to a MySQL database using the MariaDB driver. This is known to cause issues. An upgrade to Oracle's MySQL JDBC driver is highly recommended.
Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.010s)
Creating Schema History table: `test1`.`flyway_schema_history`
Current version of schema `test1`: << Empty Schema >>
Migrating schema `test1` to version 1.0 - init
Successfully applied 1 migration to schema `test1` (execution time 00:00.290s)
```

As you can see, although it works, there is a warning about issues using the MariaDB driver with MySQL.

One other option would be to download the official [MySQL JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), add it to a `./drivers` directory and mount it in the Flyway container:

```
  flyway-service-i:
    image: boxfuse/flyway
    command: ...
    volumes:
     - "./sql:/flyway/sql"
     - "./drivers:/flyway/drivers"
```

This also worked:

```
Flyway Community Edition 5.1.4 by Boxfuse

Database: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/test1 (MySQL 8.0)
Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.011s)
Creating Schema History table: `test1`.`flyway_schema_history`
Current version of schema `test1`: << Empty Schema >>
Migrating schema `test1` to version 1.0 - init
Successfully applied 1 migration to schema `test1` (execution time 00:00.229s)
```

But to get rid of the following warning:

```
WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

I did need to add `verifyServerCertificate=false` and `useSSL=true` to the jdbc url:

```
jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/test1?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true
```

Comment: Hi, I did the changes but still get the same error. I run this mysql query from bash : select Host,User,plugin from mysql.user; and got the output :
 %         | deepti           | caching_sha2_password , that means it sill uses caching_sha2_password for user .

Comment: I suspect this is because the `docker-mysql` container already existed and the user was already created with the `caching_sha2_password` before you added the command. You can remove the existing containers with `docker-compose rm` then try again.

Comment: @Deepti-l, I have updated my answer with an explanation to update the existing user, a link to a working example repository, and an alternative solution using the official MySQL JDBC driver. Please let me know if that works for you.