# 0 how to fix Database connection Error, In description is the the code and the error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql and node.js. I am trying get a simple connection, but getting this weird error. the code i am using is this

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: 'password',
database: 'userlogin'
});
connection.connect();
```

and here is the error i am getting:

[image: and here is the error i am getting]

here is some details about the server:

[image: here is some details about the server]

Comment: what is your node js version?

Comment: seems like a outdated mysql client

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried executing this in the workbench worked for me

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Comment: This is because caching_sha2_password is introduced in MySQL 8.0, but the Node.js version is not implemented yet.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.