# undefined result in mysql query with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect mysql with node.js but I got an `undefined` when I do `console.log(result)`. This is my code:

**dbConnection.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = () => {
return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost', 
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'news_portal'
    });
}
```

**news.js**

```
const dbConnection = require('../../config/dbConnection');

module.exports = app => {
    const connection = dbConnection();
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM news', (err, result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
}
```

The database has info, and the user and password is correct. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You're not checking `err`, which could provide a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it. `err` var contained `Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`. And I found a solution to that error in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)

Basically what I did was:

1. `use mysql;`
2. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD'`

Thanks for the help.