# Mysql password problem : An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello guys i had a problem with node.js and socket.io so i did 
[that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server) :

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

And that solve my problem ! But now i can't connect to localhost:8000/...

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

What password did that request change ? How can i change it to default because that need one uper case, lower, and special one ... or were i have to put the password that i change for make work the website ... (i am using symfony3.4 i put the same password there but nothing change

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: db
database_user: root
database_password: password
mailer_transport: smtp
```

EDIT : And i have a part of js :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("Hello i am an error", err);
     }
});
```

AND that part is working .... i have an error when i change the password and when i put the real one the js part is working ... but the website still not working

Comment: Note; you should not even be using the `root` user in your code. (In most circumstances)

Comment: where can i change that and config ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value of `database_port`? If you don't know, you can try default port first `3306`

Comment: No .. Nothing change ..? i that possible to set the password to root or nothing without having this : "Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements"