# When I try to npm start, my terminal gives me an error asking me to upgrade my MySQL client

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

Whenever I try to run or start my node.js project, it gives me an error and tells me to upgrade my MySQL client but I already tried to reinstall MySQL but still doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio Code and MySQL Workbench.

My terminal:

```
    Kovis-MBP:VideoJotter kovitan$ npm start

    > vidjot@1.0.0 start /Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter
    > node app.js

    (node:822) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
    Server started on port 5000
    Error: SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "vidjot",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Video Jotter",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
     },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "Chew Phuay Hern",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
        "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.0",
        "express-session": "^1.15.6",
        "flash-messenger": "^1.1.1",
        "method-override": "^3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "sequelize": "^5.7.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "node-dev": "^4.0.0"
      }
    }
```

When I enter 'npm start' or 'npm run start' into my terminal, it gives me this error when I try to go onto localhost:5000 on my browser

```
    Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
        at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:124:18)
        at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
        at Parser.write (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
        at Protocol.write (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
        at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
        --------------------
        at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
        at Protocol.handshake (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
        at PoolConnection.connect (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
        at Pool.getConnection (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
        at Pool.query (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
        at MySQLStore.query (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:432:33)
        at MySQLStore.get (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:162:8)
        at session (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express-session/index.js:460:11)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at cookieParser (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:71:5)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        at /Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
        at Function.process_params (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
        at next (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
        at methodOverride (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/method-override/index.js:65:14)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (/Users/kovitan/Desktop/student_codes end of practical 08/student_codes/VideoJotter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
```

How do I get over this problem? I'm completely stuck. I tried to use npm install, npm install -g npm, but to no avail.

Comment: If you are using MySql 8.0
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)

Comment: @Aparna I viewed that before but I don't get what they're trying to say. I'm an absolute beginner at MySQL and VSC so I'm not too sure about what they meant by query and all that

Comment: Open MySQL workbench, click on File -> New Query and execute the command given in the thread.