# NodeJS mysql module transforms localhost to 127.0.0.1 and fails connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection, proxysql

I am using the [`mysql` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to connect to ProxySQL that is set-up to connect to a MySQL database. From command line, the following works:

```
mysql -u demo1 -P6033 --database=database -p
```

However, this does not work.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port": 6033,
        "user": "demo1",
        "password" : "password as above",
        "database": "database"
    })
 connection.connect( (err) => { console.log(err.stack) } )
```

This is the error message.

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'demo1'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

The user was created as

```
CREATE USER 'demo1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I tried adding another user as `'demo'@'127.0.0.1'` and granted privileges for the same; didn't work.

How do I retain the definition above and get `mysql` to return a successful connection?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Thanks to this SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831/919480

Two things.

1. MySQL has to be told to use `mysql_native_password`. I think, this is related to the choice of option 'Strong Password' when installing MySQL.
2. The host parameter should not be `localhost` because on Unix, it is treated differently. That is, the connection is via a socket. Therefore, set host parameter to `127.0.0.1`. Or, remove host parameter and use `socketPath`.

Some discussion here too - https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2248