# client not supporting server authentication protocol on Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I developed a NodeJs app on windows and ported it back to centos to host. I try to run my code and I get
`ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`. I tried to use mysql_native_password amd flusing privileges as mentioned [MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server). My version: `8.0.19`. And I am using the latest iteration of mysql for nodejs.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems for me adding the option `insecureAuth: true` has solved it. But I suppose this is a temporary fix. Let me know if there's anything better.