# Connecting to mysql in an electron app: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron

I am new to all three Electron Mysql and JS

I was trying to connect to my database "school" with table "student"

Kindly help

Index.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')
app.on('ready', _ => {
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host  : 'localhost',
       users : 'root',
       password: '123456',
       database: 'school'
    })
    connection.connect(function(err) {
       if (err) {
         console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack)
         return
       }
       console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId)
    })
})
```

Screenshot of Error attached

[image]

Comment: try updating mysql npm package to the latest one

Comment: i used the command 'npm install mysql' yesterday only....I guess it will install the latest package only

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831/6771708

Comment: @namila007 tried this
alter user@localhost.....
and also tried
alter user.....
stilll not working

Comment: your connection  profile is wrong

Comment: i created and tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection profile is wrong, there is no `users` option. this is the working profile >

```
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host  : 'localhost',
     user : 'root',
     password: '123456',
     database: 'school'
  })
```

You can check npm mysql [docs from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction)