# Node.js, connect to database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to query a database on my website's hosting service (HostWinds). However, when I run the following code nothing happens. No error, no console logs, nothing.

I found this code from W3 schools guide on MySQL and Node.js.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "webmaxlabs.com",
  user: "abc",
  password: "123",
  database: "USER_wp4"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

I have MySQL installed, and I'm using the same username and password I use to login to HostWinds. I am also pretty sure I have the right database name. Is my host misnamed? I am not really sure what to use since 'localhost' can't be correct, right? WebMaxLabs.com is listed as my 'Main Domain' in my cPanel. So I figured it might be my host, but I am really not sure. My

Any feedback or information would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: pls try to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of webmaxlabs.com

Comment: I tried both and am getting a couple different errors. I thought it couldn't be localhost though because I'm trying to access files on a remote server.

Comment: what errors log said?

Comment: I'm getting a "connect ETIMEDOUT" error. I'm seeing in some other threads it may have something to do with networks/proxies.

Comment: Yes, I think so. what version of Node.js you are using?

Comment: I am using v12.16.1

Comment: Ok, is your MySQL running on a different port?

Comment: Actually, I am getting a "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR". Here is the first line of the message "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'rxbrnshw'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: I think you set up a wrong username or password.

Comment: I think my username was supposed to be "rxbrnshw@localhost" instead of just "rxbrnshw". Now I'm getting a different error. "ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client"

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, by the way.

Comment: Yes you need to upgrade MySql Version. or you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server

Answer (score 0):

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express()


var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO movie (movie_name,movie_review) VALUES ('inception','good movie')";
    con.query(sqlInsert, (error, result) => {
        res.send("Data send to the Database")
    })

})

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("running on port 3001")
})
```