# RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "sourceStart" is out of range. It must be <= 9. Received 13

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i am trying to insert a row in my supermasters table by creatin a pool-

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql');

const pool = createPool({
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    host: process.env.Host,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: 'users',
    connectionLimit: 8,
});

module.exports = pool;
```

My supermasters table has these columns:--

```
username varchar(10) PK 
password varchar(20) 
fullname varchar(20) 
email varchar(30) 
phoneNumber varchar(10)
```

Specifically i am getting error in this part of code which creates connection:--

```
const pool = require('../../config/database');

module.exports = {
    create: (data, callback) => {
        const my_query = 'insert into supermasters(username,password,fullname,email,phoneNumber) values(?,?,?,?,?)';

        pool.query(my_query, [data.username, data.password, data.fullname, data.email, data.phoneNumber], (error, results, fields) => {

            if (error)
                return callback(error);
            else {
                return callback(null, results);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And my error is:--

```
Server running at port 3000
D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "sourceStart" is out of range. It must be <= 9. Received 13
    at _copy (buffer.js:240:11)
    at Buffer.copy (buffer.js:768:12)
    at Parser.parseBuffer (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:272:16)
    at HandshakeInitializationPacket.parse (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\packets\HandshakeInitializationPacket.js:34:37)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:272:12)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\web-development\elite\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Do you have any field in your Database table with name 'sourceStart'?

Comment: What port are you connecting to? What is running on that port? I'd guess it's something other than mysql or using TLS on a non tls port or maybe an old/unsupported version.

Comment: no i don't have any field name 'sourceStart'. My server is running on port 3000 and database on 3306.

Answer (score 2):

What I found was that I was using the wrong port: '33060' instead of '3306',
I would suggest that you ensure that your environment variables are all correct

Maybe try to hard code the createPool() inputs, while testing before delegating them to the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved-
I ran this query in mysql workbench:-
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

Which i found here:-

[MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)