# Can't see tables in database when I connect the mysql by sql toos in vscode

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, sqltools

When I use vscode extension SQL_tools to connect my local Mysql database, the connection is successful, but I can't see the tables that have been already stored in my database, the issue is "Running the contributed command: 'sqltools.getChildrenForTreeItem' failed.", How can I deal with it?

[the issue apprear in the right corner of vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4NjG.png)

Comment: does the connection string contain a valid mysql account thatis allowed to see this database

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think my connection string valid with server address is localhost and port is 3306

Answer (score 2):

With me was because of the `caching_sha2_password`. See if this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831/15269357

I had the same problem too, and that's how I resolved

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue ... try this out...it works for me

1. Delete the existing "**MySQL** **connection**" on which this error is occured in VSCode using right click "**Delete Connection**"
2. You will not loose any existing database or any table.
3. So create new "**Add new connection**" then select "**MySQL connection**" with same **existing database** on which this error is occuring. TEST it .Save connection and connect now. Thats it.You can see every databases and table again.

**And always check on which database you are active in 'EDIT CONNECTION' while creating new database and table**

Without DROPPING table it will not vanish from your database automatically in VScode. VSCODE has this type of bug that we can encounter.