# When trying to alter my password for node js: ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Tags: mysql, node.js, strapi

I'm having problems installing strapi with mysql:

```
npx create-strapi-app my-app
```

I then select custom in stall and enter all of my credentials. I then get this error:

```
⛔️ Connection test failed: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

[From this thread it says:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

When I do that I get this error:

> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

It says I'm running:

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

> Your MySQL connection id is 11

> Server version: 8.0.23 Homebrew

I'm on a Macbook air M1 using Big Sur

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the password validation to low before altering your password:

`SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy = LOW;`

Note, if you're worried about security this is probably not the way to go.