# Node.js cannot connect mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND whitedark
```

I am just connecting to mySQL. I installed mysql with `npm install mysql` command. This is my code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host: 'whitedark',
        user: 'whitedark',
        password: 'password'
    });

con.connect(function(err)
{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected');
});
```

There is this error.
{
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'whitedark',
fatal: true
}
Where is wrong? When I typed `SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;` I get this response. User = whitedark, Host = %, Plugin = caching_sha2_password, ........, User = root, Host = localhost, Plugin = mysql_native_password.

Comment: The error you're getting indicates that your NodeJS app can't resolve the hostname 'whitedark' to an IP address. If the MySQL server is on the same host as the script, you can use 'localhost', otherwise you need to put a valid IP address or DNS name in the `host` property.

Comment: When I use 'localhost' I got this error, any improvement? Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Comment: This answer details that error and what to do about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server/56509065#56509065

Comment: I got it. It connected. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)