# Express mysql session store with Typescript

Tags: typescript, express, session, nestjs, session-store

I'm trying to create a mysql session storage in NestJS with Typescript. I have installed the express-session, express-mysql-session and @types/express-mysql-session package. The code below compiles (main.ts file), but then there's an error in the console:

```
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { env } from "./common/env";
import session from "express-session";
import MySQLStore from "express-mysql-session";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: { credentials: env.ENABLE_CORS, origin: env.CLIENT_HOST },
  });

  //session store
  const options = {
    host: "db",
    port: 3306,
    user: env.DB_USER,
    password: env.DB_PASSWD,
    database: env.DATABASE,
    checkExpirationInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
    expiration: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  };

  const store = MySQLStore(session);
  const sessionStore = new store(options);

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: env.COOKIE_SECRET,
      store: sessionStore,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      },
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(env.PORT_BACKEND || 8080);
}
bootstrap();
```

And the error is
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mWfF.png)

Doing it with require instead of import won't even compile, I have tried the express-mysql-session package way:

`var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);`

How should I make it work? Or is there another better package for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I made it work. Ended up installing also mysql2 package, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server) why.

Code ended up like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { env } from "./common/env";
import { AppModule } from "./modules/app/app.module";
import * as session from "express-session";
import * as MySQLStoreCreator from "express-mysql-session";
import * as mysql2 from "mysql2/promise";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: { credentials: env.ENABLE_CORS, origin: env.CLIENT_HOST },
  });

  //session store
  const options = {
    host: "db",
    port: 3306,
    user: env.DB_USER,
    password: env.DB_PASSWD,
    database: env.DATABASE,
    checkExpirationInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
    expiration: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  };

  const connection = mysql2.createPool(options);
  const sessionStore = new (MySQLStoreCreator(session))({}, connection);

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: env.COOKIE_SECRET,
      store: sessionStore,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      },
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(env.PORT_BACKEND || 8080);
}
bootstrap();
```

Maybe someone will find it helpful C:

Comment: When I change from `import session from 'express-session';` to `import * as session from 'express-session';` I get an error "This expression is not callable." on line `app.use(session({`... How do I get around that?