# Not able to connect MySQL server running on docker with Node-Red container

Tags: mysql, azure, docker, node-red

I have a VM (OS: Ubuntu 18.04) running in azure cloud in which I have installed docker. In docker I have two containers MySQL(8.0.20)  and node-red(v2.1.3), I am trying to connect my MySQL with node-red and I get the following error message in Node-Red

"Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client"".

MySQL is working fine, I am able to access the database via putty but somehow I am not able to make a successful connection with node-red as well as Grafana.

I am using following configuration. My VM's IP address is 20.107.194.152 and MySQL port is 3306

[image: Node-red config]

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to edit the question to include what version of MySQL you are running and which MySQL Node-RED node you have installed.

Comment: Hi @hardillb, My MySQL version is  8.0.20 and Node Red is v2.1.3.

Comment: You've not answered which MySQL node you are using, there are several

Comment: This looks to be the problem and workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065/504554 I have opened an issue to loo at updating the `node-red-node-mysql` package to use the new mysql2 library https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/issues/853