# problems with connecting Node JS to MySQl workbench

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I am using below lines **:**

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql2 = require("mysql")
var app = mysql2();
var app = express();
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App Listening on port 3000');
});
```

Everytime I try to run: node index.js I receive below error **:**

> ReferenceError: mysql2 is not defined

Please, advise how that can be solved and what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem is you can not create two same variables - app.
Second, I think what you want to do is to connect the MySQL database, the code  should be

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({ 
    user: "root",
    host: "localhost",
    password: "password",
    database: "your_database_name",
  });
```

If you encounter Client authentication protocol problems, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server).
Third, when you get a request from the client and want to have some modification to the database, you can have code like

```
app.post("/modify", async (req, res) => {
  await modifyDatabase(req.body); // your modify function
  res.status(200).send();
});
```