# Can Auth0 be integrated into a MySql 8 database?

Tags: mysql, auth0

I have a problem with Auth0 integration with MySql database.
I am also in contact with Auth0 support, but so far they have not been able to help me.

I have a server set up, and on it a MySql database, in it tables with users - id, nickname, email and password.

When I try to connect to the database using the scripts provided by Auth0 I get a return:

> "ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication
> protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client".

I tried the solutions listed in the thread:
[MySQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)
namely entering commands into the database:

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'root123'

create user 'root'@'peu-a-ec1-2.outbound.auth0user.net' identified with mysql_native_password by 'root123'

flush privileges;
```

or changing the library to mysql2 on the MySql scripts side - nothing helps.

Here scripts from official docs:
https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/database-connections/custom-db/templates/login#mongodb

Comment: You haven't provided any of these "scripts"

Comment: sorry, my bad, from official docs: https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/database-connections/custom-db/templates/login#mongodb