# Test server using mysql with Github Actions (and docker compose)

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose, jestjs, github-actions

I just begin in the devops world and for my project, I have to realize a classic CI/CD pipeline using github actions. For my project, I made a simple website where a user can bet winning for some football games I entered in my DB.

My project uses MySQL for the database, Nodejs backend and Nextjs front end. I made a docker compose file to build everything together. Finally, I wrote some tests (only for the server for the moment). Here is the deal :

After I run docker-compose up locally, running 'npm test' runs my tests. The first test is to check the connection to the database. Everything works fine.

But now I want to do the same, but with the github actions, so I cannot push a commit if this doesn't pass my tests of course. However, on github, my first test (connection to the DB) never works, even if I run docker-compose before.

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build the Docker images 
      working-directory: ./project
      run: docker-compose build

    - name: Run the docker compose
      working-directory: ./project
      run: docker-compose up -d

    - name: install server dependencies
      working-directory: ./project/server
      run: npm ci

    - name: run servers test
      working-directory: ./project/server
      run: npm test

    - name: finish docker down
      working-directory: ./project
      run: docker-compose down
```

And here is my error:
[image: Github action error]

Also, and I think it has an important role of course, when I run all this locally, I have my '.env' file with mysql passwords etc.. and I don't understand how my app can get these information on github.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it works, here is how I did. Please, feel free to give me advices if you have to do it better, thank you in advance.

So my problem came from the fact that imagined github action like a VM where everything happens as on my local machine. But it's not really the case I think now because running `docker compose up -d` in a step of my github action doesn't create a mysql instance with my db that I can now access as I do on my PC. I can't because if I want to use mysql for my actions, I need to use the one on the machine I declare at the beginning of my github action with `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`, or the container I made will just conflict with it.

After some research, I found out the mysql service doesn't start by default with github actions (see :[GitHub Actions Breaking Change: Ubuntu virtual environments will no longer start the MySQL service automatically](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-02-21-github-actions-breaking-change-ubuntu-virtual-environments-will-no-longer-start-the-mysql-service-automatically/)). So, in my yml file I deleted the docker compose part and add the command line to start mysql on the ubuntu machine and load my sql init file. Here is my github action's code :

```yaml
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: start mysql
      run: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

    - name: Create test database
      run: mysql -uroot -proot < project/db/init.sql

    - name: install server dependencies
      working-directory: ./project/server
      run: npm ci

    - name: run servers test
      working-directory: ./project/server
      run: npm test
```

For testing, I am using [jest-mysql](https://github.com/Daniel-Yonkov/jest-mysql), which uses `mysql` instead of `mysql2` and got me the error : ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client. I ended up by adding the following couple lines in my `init.sql` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077512/19858170) answer on another stackoverflow question, and changed my config file's username and password according to it.

```sql
CREATE USER 'sqluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sqluser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now it is finally working, my tests works well but as you noticed, I am pretty sure there are better way to come to this end. This is a little private school project so I am allowed to make mistake, but I would love to learn how to avoid them for the next time!

Thank you for your time and merry Christmas!