# MySQL Workbench Connection is not established and cannot start process from services

Tags: mysql

Already for 4th time I have the same problem: **MySQL Workbench 8.0** shows me `Connection is not established` error:

[image]

All advices in the net tells me to go to the services and press `Start` to start this service BUT when I try to do it, all the time I receive the following error:

[image]

Of course I tried to fix it and tried to find some info, but none of the solutions from the net hasn't resolved my problem. So I have to reinstall MySQL Workbench with server after every time this error occurs.

**Update by @Shadow advice:**
Attach windows event log:
[image]

All matched with red triangle ERRORs relate to mysql

Error text from the photo:

```
Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 8.0.32.0, time stamp: 0x639ca47a
Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 8.0.32.0, time stamp: 0x639ca47a
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000194d055
Faulting process id: 0x3a78
Faulting application start time: 0x01d976223b334333
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe
Report Id: 26b0106c-f038-4e0e-bb22-a2105f759e0a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I don't know if I have to add any other information, tell me if any addition info needed

Comment: "SQL Service" is a bit suspicious name, I'm almost certain it should be "MySQL Service" or something similar. Did you install MySQL correctly?

Comment: You need to check the windows event log for more information as to why the service stopped. Sql is an unusual nsme for a mysql instance. Are you sure that's your mysql instance in the first place?

Comment: @Shadow SQL Service was created by myself when I was setting up in MySQL installer, as 3 previous times I chose names like MySQL80 MySQL8 MySQL800 etc. And the problem was with those names too. As I couldn't succeed to resolve this "started and stopped" problem, I reinstalled MySQL many times and chose different names

Comment: @jurez check please my comment

Comment: @Shadow updated my question with windows event log

Comment: Thiese are errors within mysqld itself. You need to contact mysql for support.

Comment: @Shadow I've asked this question on MySQL forum, and after a week of waiting didn't receive an answer. How do I contact MySQL Support directly?