# Using VSC and SQLTools to connect to an older MySQL database ( insecureAuth:true)

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, sqltools

At the place I work we make some use of databases, IT administrates them, we have a few older databases on the network, I have been able to connect to all the databases via HeidiSQL and using ODBC, but I want to use VSC to design queries

when I attempt to connect to a newer database on my network the wizard is sufficient to connect to that database.

When I try to connect to an older database on my network I get a popup from VSC:

> Error opening connection MySQL server is requesting the old and insecure pre-4.1 auth mechanism. Upgrade the user password or use the {insecureAuth: true} option.
> Source: SQLTools (Extension)

I have my code-workspace file and my current assumption is that if I put the parameter insecureAuth: true in next to authProtocol that would be sufficient (hint: it is not, different error `Error opening connection ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake`) I have also tried a variable object to the initial response

```
{
    "folders": [...],   
        "settings": {...
        "sqltools.connections": [...

            {
                "mysqlOptions": {
                    "authProtocol": "default",
                                        "insecureAuth": true
                },
                "previewLimit": 50,
                "server": "x.x.x.x",
                "port": ####,
                "driver": "MySQL",
                "name": "Old",
                "group": "myDatabases",
                "database": "old",
                "username": "memyselfnI"
            }}}}
```

`"variables":{"insecureAuth":true,},...`

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50093144/11107541