# "Client does not support authentication protocol" trying to connect to local MySql database with NestJs app

Tags: mysql, nestjs, database-connection, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to connect my NestJs application to my MySql database locally.
Fellowing the NestJs [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) .

I get this error message:

```
[Nest] 8696  - 24/08/2023 15:14:40   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

**Here's my database provider :**

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'DATA_SOURCE_LOCAL',
    useFactory: async () => {
      const dataSource = new DataSource({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'myDb',
        entities: [myEntities],
        synchronize: true,
        insecureAuth: true,
      });

      return dataSource.initialize();
    },
  },
```

**An example of provider (user.prividers.ts) :**

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import {User} from './user.entity';
import { Profile } from './profile.entity';

export const userProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'USER_REPOSITORY',
    useFactory: (dataSource: DataSource) => dataSource.getRepository(User),
    inject: ['DATA_SOURCE_LOCAL'],
  }
];
```

As the documentation preconizes, I'm using "mysql2" and "typeorm" :
**My package.json file :**

```
{
  "name": "mysql-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.4",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.0",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
```

I precise a "funny" thing.
Each time than I run the application, I get one (and ony one) new table/entity in the database.

I have 4 entities (Quiz, Question, User, Profile). Id the table "Quiz" is set in database, and I run the app, it will crash with the above message, but the "Question" table will be creatad.

**I've already tried this method :**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
flush privileges;
```

But, despite the fact than it's not working, it seems to not be a good practice (like in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server)) and no usable in every situations (cloud database for exemple).

I question myself on the use of "mysql" type in the database provider dans the need of "mysql2" from the documentation (which is founded nowhere in the app).

I read things about "mysql2" whith Node.js like add this to index.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')
```

But I don't know how to use that with NestJs.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` npm module still doesn't support the `caching_sha2_password` authentication introduced in MySQL 8. So, the solution is to switch to the `mysql2` npm module which does.

Answer (score 0):

For me
I had to uninstall mysql and then install mysql2

> `
> npm uninstall mysql

`
then

> npm install mysql2

It worked for me.