ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE Error even though mysql2 is being used
I am receiving an error

ERROR [ExceptionHandler] ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

every time I try to run my app on a docker container. I switched to mysql2, then I switched to mysql2/promise and I am still getting the error. I am not sure what I should do but I have spent weeks on this and I would like to go through the more secure route. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? I know many people have posted the same question but none of the responses to these questions have solved my problem, not sure if having it on a docker container makes a difference or if there is something trivial that is missing.
Here is the main.ts for my NestJS app:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as serveStatic from 'serve-static';
...
import mysql, { Pool } from 'mysql2/promise';

async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3001', credentials: true }));

  const mySqlStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
  const APP_PORT: string = process.env.APP_PORT || '3000';
  const IN_PROD: boolean = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

  const options = {
    connectionLimit: 10,
    connectTimeout: 10,
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.PORT), // db port
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    createDatabaseTable: true,
  };

  const pool: Pool = mysql.createPool(options);
  const sessionStore = new mySqlStore(options, pool);

  // Set up the session middleware
  ...
  // Initialize and set up the Passport session middleware
  ...

  await app.listen(APP_PORT);
}

bootstrap().catch((err) => console.error(err));


You need to check the server log to get more information, but it certainly sounds like your server is not set up to allow unencrypted external connections using a plain password.  However, you can't use the same APP_PORT for the database and your server.

Ah good catch but this doesn't fix it. the logs don't add much more, they just give the same error over and over: Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

It maybe solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server

The error has nothing to do with your code. You need to check what authentication plugin is configured for the mysql user account and you may have to chamge that to one that is supported by mysql2

I have already tried the solution from this question and you would see that if you read the whole question. I am not sure why my question was closed but I clearly state that the answer to this question did not solve my problem.
