# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've read all the similar/duplicate questions, but none of them seem to help.

I am using **node** with the **[mysql npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)** package.

I am able to log into mysql with no problem from the terminal...

```sh
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

...but unable to do via node.

Here is the error.

```
if (error) throw error;
               ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/ivan/lab/posto/server/database/createDatabase.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
```

The database connection.

```
rdbms: {
        server: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        port: 3306
    }
```

The code I'm trying to execute.

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let rdbms = require("../config").rdbms;

let connection = mysql.createConnection(rdbms);

connection.connect();

let query = `
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS dbname;
    CREATE DATABASE dbname;
`

connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("Database created!");
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: When you run mysql from terminal what password do you use when prompted? If its not `root` then thats why you get the connection error. There is no password set

Comment: Should the query be wrapped in quotes and not backticks?

Comment: Does nodes connector allow multiple command in one query? Like Drop and Create ??

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1. There is a password set. 2. Backticks are valid in Javascript for multi-line code. 3. Yes, it works in other places.

Comment: Should there be a `;` after the second backtick?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope, the code is valid.

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` So did you use the right password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS/mySQL - ER\_ECCESS\_DENIED\_ERROR Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477625/nodejs-mysql-er-eccess-denied-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I am providing a valid password.

Comment: @SkandaShastry Yes, it is a duplicate, which provided no help.

Comment: Are you running the MySQL Server and the Web site on the same machine?